# Unable to seed a table in database due to 'The property 'xx' on entity type 'IdentityUserRole<int>' has a temporary value

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to show available dates and available times for an entity - an instructor, however, I am running into a problem when I try to seed some data for new entity and the error message isn't even (or at least it seems like it) related to the entities I am adding.

The idea is that an Instructor has a list of available dates.

The error I am getting in the Output once I start debugging is:

The property 'UserId' on entity type "IdentityUserRole< int > has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

The application then continues to run fine, but the data I'm attempting to seed never ends up in the database.

I'm sure that I am overlooking something or that I have configured something wrong, any help would be appreciated, if more info is required please let me know.

If it helps, I'm using .NET Core 2.2 with EF Core 2.2 and SQL Server as a db provide

I already attempted dropping & recreating the database I double checked the relationships, but nothing seems to help. I'm also making sure that I'm seeding in correct order.

Here are the entities which are causing the error:

```
public class AvailableDate
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AvailableDateId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public List<AvailableDateAvailableTime> AvailableDateAvailableTimes { get; set; 
}

public class AvailableTime
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AvailableTimeId { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan From { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan To { get; set; }

        public List<AvailableDateAvailableTime> AvailableDateAvailableTimes { get; set; }

}


public class AvailableDateAvailableTime
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AvailableDateAvailableTimeId { get; set; }

        public int AvailableDateId { get; set; }
        public AvailableDate AvailableDate { get; set; }
        public int AvailableTimeId { get; set; }
        public AvailableTime AvailableTime { get; set; }
}


Seed method - if I put a breakpoint at the end I can see that the correct values are filled in, they just never get saved to the database.

 private static IEnumerable<AvailableDate> FillAvailableDates()
 {
            var today = DateTime.Now;

            var availableDates = new List<AvailableDate>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
            {
                availableDates.Add(new AvailableDate
                {
                    Date = today.Date
                });

                today = today.AddDays(1);
            }

            return availableDates;
}

// Seeding available dates - never succeeds even though the data is correct
private static IEnumerable<AvailableDate> FillAvailableDates()
{
            var today = DateTime.Now;

            var availableDates = new List<AvailableDate>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
            {
                availableDates.Add(new AvailableDate
                {
                    Date = today.Date
                });

                today = today.AddDays(1);
            }

            return availableDates;
}
```

As soon as I comment-out invocation of seed method for that table, the error is not there anymore:

```
        //if (!context.AvailableDates.Any())
        //{
        //    context.AddRange(FillAvailableDates());
        //    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //}
```

Seeding available time works fine

```
private static IEnumerable<AvailableTime> FillAvailableTimes()
{
            var timespan = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);

            var timeblocks = new List<AvailableTime>();

            var today = DateTime.Now;

            var initialTime = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 08, 00, 0);


            for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
                timeblocks.Add(new AvailableTime
                {
                    From = initialTime.TimeOfDay,
                    To = initialTime.TimeOfDay + timespan
                });

                initialTime += timespan;
            }

            return timeblocks;
}
```

I also have similar entities with the same relationships that are not causing a problem:

```
// User base is just a class with some common user info
public class Instructor : UserBase
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int InstructorId { get; set; }

        //removed some props for readability...
        public List<AvailableDate> AvailableDates { get; set; }
        public List<InstructorSubject> InstructorSubjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<InstructorSubject> InstructorSubjects { get; set; }
}

public class InstructorSubject
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int InstructorSubjectId { get; set; }

        public int InstructorId { get; set; }
        public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public Subject Subject { get; set; }
}

// Seeding instructors, then subjects, then instructor subjects

private static IEnumerable<InstructorSubject> FillInstructorSubjects()
{
            //  Assign to instructor subjects list
            _instructorSubjects = new List<InstructorSubject>()
            {
                new InstructorSubject()
                {
                    InstructorId = 1,
                    SubjectId = 1
                },

                new InstructorSubject()
                {
                    InstructorId = 1,
                    SubjectId = 2
                }
                //etc...
            }
            return _instructorSubjects;
}


¸¸¸¸
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!--jQuery-->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--css-->

  <style type="text/css">
    *{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    .carousel{
      overflow:hidden;
      white-space:nowrap;

    }
    .img{
      display:inline;
      position:relative;
      max-width:900px;
      height:auto;
    }
  </style>


  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
         <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>

<body>

  <section >
        <div class="carousel">
      <div class="img"><img src="images/slide-show-1.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="img"><img src="images/slide-show-2.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="img"><img src="images/slide-show-3.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="img"><img src="images/slide-show-4.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    </section>

  <script>

    function slide(){

      var img = $('.img');
      var firstImg = img.first();
      var lastImg = img.last()
      var firstImagePos = firstImg.position().left;

      img.animate({left:firstImagePos-900});

      //alert('First image is '+$('.img img').first().attr('src') + '\
' + 'And First Image Pos is '+firstImagePos);

      if(firstImagePos < -900){
        firstImg.insertAfter(lastImg);
      }

    }

    setInterval(function() {
      //slide();
    }, 2000);


  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: oops really so sorry